# Installing Sylius with eZ Publish 5

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composer-php, sylius, ezpublish

I have problems installing Sylius Bundle. Here is the error when i try to access the web site or when i try to update composer :

[RuntimeException]
"Cannot find Doctrine RTEL"

Here is my config :

composer.json

```
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "sylius/money-bundle": "0.12",
    "sylius/order-bundle": "0.12",
    "sylius/product-bundle": "0.12",
    "sylius/resource-bundle": "0.12",
    "sylius/cart-bundle": "0.12"
```

config.yml

```
    stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
# Sylius
sylius_cart:
    resolver: app.cart_item_resolver 
    classes: ~
sylius_order:
    driver: doctrine/orm 
    classes:
        order:
            model: Project\EshopBundle\Entity\Order
sylius_money: ~
sylius_product:
    driver: doctrine/orm 
    classes:
        product:
            model: Project\EshopBundle\Entity\Product
sylius_attribute:
    driver: doctrine/orm 
sylius_variation:
    driver: doctrine/orm
```

Kernel.php

```
        // Sylius Order Bundle dependencies
        new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
        new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
        new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
        new Sylius\Bundle\MoneyBundle\SyliusMoneyBundle(),
        new Sylius\Bundle\OrderBundle\SyliusOrderBundle(),

        // Sylius Ressources Bundle dependencies
        new Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle(),

        // Sylius Cart Bundle dependencies
        new Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\SyliusCartBundle(),

        // Sylius Product Bundle
        new Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\SyliusProductBundle(),
        new Sylius\Bundle\AttributeBundle\SyliusAttributeBundle(),
        new Sylius\Bundle\VariationBundle\SyliusVariationBundle(),

        new DoctrineBundle()
```

eZ Publish version : 2014.11

Thanks.

Comment: What is the configuration for `doctrine`? Seems like you didn't configure ORM

Comment: I have no specific conf for doctrine ORM, i'm guessing it is using the default conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure doctrine to enable ORM like this: (example taken from the [Symfony Standard Edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.7/app/config/config.yml))

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: Yep ! That did it, but i read somewhere that if doctrine isn't configured, it will use the default conf ... guess it is wrong. 

now I have : Unable to replace alias "app.cart_item_resolver" with "sylius.cart_resolver".

Comment: @Kabylzki it will use default conf, but that means no ORM enabled (ORM is quite a heavy beast and doctrineBundle is also targetted for pure DBAL users). If you have a new question, please open a new one using the "Ask Question" button.